# MySQL sanitize on mysql_fetch_row

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I have the following code:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];      
$query = ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$user_id = $row[0];
```

Where should I apply mysql_real_escape_string here? 
Would `$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($row[0]);` work?

I know that MySQL should be left in the past. I'll move to MySQLi soon enough.

Comment: Nowhere. You ought to use prepared statements instead.

Comment: You want to apply it to potential user input, not your output

Comment: Ok. So I should use mysql_real_escape_string only for $_POST['something'], right?

Comment: Please note that all the `mysql_xxx()` functions in PHP are deprecated and have been considered obsolete for years. You really need to read [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Great source of information! :)

Comment: @SporeDev not just for $_POST, **anything** that could potentially come from the user should be escaped, POST, GET, SESSION, COOKIE etc... as a rule of thumb, **never** trust any input coming from a user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this in first line:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
```

and change query to this:

```
$query = ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'");
```

Comment: Thank you Adam. I want to ask you something. Why did you wrote the query the way you did? It's a concatanation, is it not?

Comment: @SporeDev Query doesn't need to change, so long as the first line comes above the query, the concatenation makes no difference to the query, other than any performance differences.

Comment: Would those performance differences be for the better or worst?

Comment: @SporeDev - FDL's right. This form of query is in my opinion clearer.

Comment: @SporeDev there is no difference. it's just a matter of taste

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) @SporeDev Don't forget to approve the answer ;)